# TIMESTAMP as a key and its default value

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1067: Invalid default value for 'Users_Created'

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kwestionariusz_db`.`Companies` (
  `CompanyId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `Name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `Users_UserId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `Users_Created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyId`, `Created`, `Users_UserId`, `Users_Created`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Companies_Users1` (`Users_UserId` ASC, `Users_Created` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Companies_Users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Users_UserId` , `Users_Created` )
    REFERENCES `kwestionariusz_db`.`Users` (`UserId` , `Created` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

So, basically, what did I did wrong? I don't want Users_Created to be updated while creating Company, this would break the relation. Also - is Companies.Created going to be updated while changing e.g. Companies.EMail? I wouldn't want that either, obviously, but making foreign key a null-able is kind of wrong anyway, right? So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Users_Created` column is a part of the primary key. Primary keys cannot contain nullable columns.

Comment: Right, so what default value should the Users_Created has? AFAIK, it has to has one... but it's also foreign key so it shouldn't has CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value, right? It would break the relation... or is it going to be overruled by importing the reference? If that so, why coudn't I just leave default value empty...

Comment: because if I add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default value it goes "ERROR: Error 1293: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause" so should I just insert some abstract value? This is not very elegant I believe...

Comment: You apparently intend it to be nullable (when a company has been created but a user has not), so you cannot include it in the primary key. As a matter of fact, I cannot understand the logic behind adding a timestamp column to a primary key.

Comment: I intend Companies.Users_Created to be exactly the same as Users.Created and I want no possibility to create Company instance without referring to the User instance... timestamp column as a primary key was IMO convenient when editing the same row by multiple users but you're probably right and it can be better made within a application logic. But I just feel like there shoudn't be default value required. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
`Users_Created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
```

For a complete guide on TIMESTAMP initialization, read this reference doc:

[11.3.4. Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)